# [Google Drive Android SDK]How to get notification when uploading a file successfully or unsuccessfully?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I used example code to upload video files:

```
Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getContents()).setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

Is there any way to know when the video is already uploaded successfully or unsuccessfully (failed reason)? Now my result callback is called immediately, but there is no video file in the Google Drive backend. Does any one know?
Thanks.

Comment: did you get this working? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: Hi Harish, you could refer to the link:https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion, however I don't know how to associate the event parameter of onCompletion with the result parameter of DriveFileResult? I want to know which file(drive id) is successfully(unsuccessfully) upload or not

Answer (score 0):

Not need to get notification.

Only send notification.

Refer this link

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Comment: Hi Ginoya, sorry to confuse you. However your response is not my answer. Are you trying to promote your work?

Comment: Hi Ginoya, do you mean by https://developers.google.com/drive/web/push#api-events ? If it is, it is not Google Drive Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The newly released Completion Event feature can be used to determine when files have been uploaded to the server. It is also possible to respond to conflicts.

Please see the documentation for more information:
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, do you know how to associate the event parameter of onCompletion with the result parameter of DriveFileResult? I want to know which file(drive id) is successfully(unsuccessfully) upload or not. Now, these driveids in DriveFileResult and onCompletion are not matched.